# WakefulBroadcastReceiver is firing non stop, after first execution of onReceive function

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

**Application Pupose**: Simple Alarm Clock.

Application is working fine on Android 4.2.1 (Jelly Beans).

***Application is totally messed up on Android 5.1.1 (Lollipop)***

Problem Detail: When the alarm time is up, Service is called. But when i turn off the alarm it is called again after 2-3 seconds delay some time instantly. No matter how many time i turn off the alarm.. activity closes and reappear again and again (Have to Swipe the application from recent apps).

Another problem is, Service idea was to make sure... that alarm keeps ringing regardless if user close the application or not.. which is woking fine on Android 4.2.1 but here if I close the application so does the alarm (Service).

Another problem: If the alarm is set and I close the application broadcast receiver wont be called. No action take place then.

Not checked on other versions yet...

I am using AlarmManager to set timer for alarm using following Code. Function is getting called from activity.

```
 public static void setAlarm(Context context, int pendingIntentCode, long timeToAlarm, int alarmMode, String alarmTitle) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "Pending Intent Code" + pendingIntentCode);
    intent.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);
    intent.putExtra("alarmMode", alarmMode);
    intent.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, pendingIntentCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, pendingIntent);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, pendingIntent);
    }


}
```

Code for BroadCast Receiver.

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int pendingIntentCode = intent.getIntExtra("pendingIntentCode", 0);
    int mode = intent.getIntExtra("alarmMode", 0);
    String alarmTitle = intent.getStringExtra("alarmTitle");

    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmByService.class);
    startServiceIntent.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);
    startServiceIntent.putExtra("alarmMode", mode);
    startServiceIntent.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);

    context.startService(startServiceIntent);

    Log.d(TAG, "on Receive");

}
```

In service class remaining functions are same... except for ondestroy where MediaPlayer.stop is called.

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    int annoyingMethod = sharedPreferences.getInt("annoyingMethod", 0);
    String calmModeTone = sharedPreferences.getString("alarm_tone_calm_mode", "default");
    String annoyingModeTone = sharedPreferences.getString("alarm_tone_annoying_mode", "default");
    vibration = sharedPreferences.getInt("vibration", 0);
    int mode = intent.getIntExtra("alarmMode", 0);
    int pendingIntentCode = intent.getIntExtra("pendingIntentCode", 0);
    String alarmTitle = intent.getStringExtra("alarmTitle");

    Intent activityToCall = null;


    if (mode == 0) {
        activityToCall = new Intent(AlarmByService.this, CalmModeAlarmDisplay.class);
        activityToCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activityToCall.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);
        activityToCall.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);

        MediaPlayerForAlarm.playAlarm(calmModeTone, this, vibration);

    } else {
        MediaPlayerForAlarm.playAlarm(annoyingModeTone, this, 1);
        switch (annoyingMethod) {
            case 0:
                activityToCall = new Intent(AlarmByService.this, DrawPattern.class);
                activityToCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activityToCall.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);
                activityToCall.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);
                break;
            case 1:
                activityToCall = new Intent(AlarmByService.this, SolveMathProblem.class);
                activityToCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activityToCall.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);
                activityToCall.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);
                break;
            case 2:
                activityToCall = new Intent(AlarmByService.this, ShakeDevice.class);
                activityToCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activityToCall.putExtra("pendingIntentCode", pendingIntentCode);
                activityToCall.putExtra("alarmTitle", alarmTitle);
                break;
        }
    }


    if (activityToCall != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Calling Activity Intent is not Null");
        startActivity(activityToCall);

    }
    if (alarmTitle == null || pendingIntentCode == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Service Unintentional Call");
        stopSelf();

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Title " + alarmTitle);
    Log.d(TAG, "Vibration: " + vibration);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmByService.this, 0, activityToCall, 0);

    Notification alarmNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AlarmByService.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(alarmTitle)
            .setContentText("Tap here to see Alarm Detail.")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1337, alarmNotification);


    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I have googled it so many time for last two days... and cant find anything... may be i am not good at googling.. Any help is WellCome...

If information provided is insufficient, i can provide more...

Thanks in Advance.